# ActionBarSherlock › How to implement TabNavigation on SherlockActionbar + RoboGuice?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, roboguice

I'm using RoboGuice+SherlockActionBar-V4.0 and building a sample app to test tab-navigation ,
I checked the roboguice-sherlock example which is coming with SherlockActionBar package but ... no help .

How can I switch the activities with the Tabs ?

```
//old method was .
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(null,
  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_capture))
  .setContent(new Intent(this,TabOne.class));
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

If any sample code is available then it should be great for me.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their sample code, you can try the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setText("Tab " + i);
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_cab_done_holo_light);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
    }
```

This works in my 2.3.3 environment, using ABS4 and RoboGuice.

Comment: How can I open different Activities for different Tabs ??

Comment: For tabs, you can use Android's Fragments API in conjunction with tabs, even in pre-Honeycomb versions (using the Android Support Package: [Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)). Each tab can be associated with a Fragment (almost like a nested Activity). See: [Tablet Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully setup Tabs on SherlockActionbar+RoboGuice with the help of this snippet .
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html ,
Sample app > https://bitbucket.org/ashish2py/sherlockrobotab